# How to unpivot a sparkR dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, unpivot, sparkr

I am trying to transpose/unpivot a dataframe in SparkR. I don't find any direct method available in SparkR package to accomplish unpivoting a dataframe. Neither I am able to use R package on a SparkR dataframe even after using includePackage method. It would be helpful if someone could let me know if there are direct ways to unpivot using SparkR or other alternatives such as Hive.

Comment: Did you manage to unpivot a SparkR dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

> Neither I am able to use R package on a SparkR dataframe

Native R commands don't run on Spark DataFrames.  Only Spark commands run on Spark DataFrames.  If you want to run an R command on a Spark DataFrame you can collect() to convert it to an R data.frame, but you lose the benefits of distributed processing.

The Spark DataFrame is a similar construct to a table in a relational database.  By working with Spark commands on a Spark DataFrame you will retain the benefits of distributed processing across the cluster.

It's difficult to answer such a general question - normally on this forum people expect specific examples with data and code.  In general, if I wanted to un-pivot a relational table then the most basic way would be to create a set of queries, each query containing the row key plus one column, filtered for non-null in the column.  I would then union together the multiple results into a new DataFrame.

If your preference is for R language syntax, that union can be done using the unionAll(x,y) command in SparkR, which will be processed across the cluster (unlike an R command on an R data.frame).